# Docusign Send Multiple Envelope to multiple Signer with one to one Document to Signer mapping

Tags: salesforce, docusignapi

I have been working on Salesforce to Docusign Integration. I have multiple documents with Specific signer for each document i.e. **one document should be send to one specific user, not all**. But I want to do this in one Rest API call to docusign! The documents are stored in Accounts attachments which are created dynamically for each user which are specific to user.

I have been trying this using [CompositeTemplates](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/Envelopes/Envelopes/create/), what I am doing is, adding document and Signer in each **inlineTemplate**, But it is sending all the documents to all the users in sequence.
I don't want to show all document to all the user, they should see only document specific to them.

Below is the JSON which I am sending:

```
{
  "status": "Sent",
  "compositeTemplates": [
    {
      "inlineTemplates": [
        {
          "sequence": "1",
          "recipients": {
            "signers": [
              {
                "roleName": "Signer 1",
                "recipientId": "1",
                "name": "Anmol",
                "email": "test@gmail.com"
              }
            ]
          },
          "envelope": {
            "status": "Sent",
            "emailSubject": "test1"
          },
          "documents": [
            {
              "name": "Doc 1",
              "fileExtension": "doc",
              "documentId": "1",
              "documentBase64": "JVBERi0xLjQKJeLjz9MKN58HkeCg8gJEomcWGJdEFtOYYklsXV2dlT6R6Owc+FXFMNSlpckKM6M/ioTGkROkEjkxBDrgthySkvMxGpQJYapHKWwcwXtRU9GCg=="
            }
          ],
          "customFields": {
            "listCustomFields": [
              {
                "value": "00128000003tPKB",
                "show": "true",
                "required": "false",
                "name": "Account",
                "fieldId": "1",
                "configurationType": "salesforce"
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ],
      "compositeTemplateId": "1"
    },
    {
      "inlineTemplates": [
        {
          "sequence": "1",
          "recipients": {
            "signers": [
              {
                "roleName": "Signer 2",
                "recipientId": "1",
                "name": "Anmol",
                "email": "test1@gmail.com"
              }
            ]
          },
          "envelope": {
            "status": "Sent",
            "emailSubject": "test2"
          },
          "documents": [
            {
              "name": "Doc 2",
              "fileExtension": "doc",
              "documentId": "2",
              "documentBase64": "JVBERi0xLjYNJeLjz9MNCjEzIDAgb2JqDTw8L0xpbmVhcmlmDQoxMTYNCiUlRU9GDQo="
            }
          ],
          "customFields": {
            "listCustomFields": [
              {
                "value": "00128000003tPKB",
                "show": "true",
                "required": "false",
                "name": "Account",
                "fieldId": "1",
                "configurationType": "salesforce"
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ],
      "compositeTemplateId": "2"
    }
  ]
}
```

Any doc, code or suggestions about the approach I am following for this will be very helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do it in a single api call, specify the [excludedDocuments](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/Envelopes/EnvelopeRecipients/#core-recipient-parameters) property in the [EnvelopeCreate](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/Envelopes/Envelopes/create/) request

> **excludedDocuments**: Specifies the documents that are not visible to the recipient. Document Visibility must be enabled for the account and the enforceSignerVisibility property must be set to true for the envelope to use this.

Here is a sample Json for  `POST /v2/accounts/{accountId}/envelopes`

Note: *I have combined both your inline templates into a single* inlineTemplate.

```
{
  "status": "Sent",
  "emailSubject": "Email Subject to all recipients",
  "emailBlurb": "Email body to all recipients",
  "compositeTemplates": [
    {
        "inlineTemplates": [
            {
                "sequence": "1",
                "recipients": {
                    "signers": [
                        {
                            "recipientId": "1",
                            "name": "recipient one",
                            "email": "recipientone@dsxtr.com",
                            "excludedDocuments": [ "2" ]
                        },
                        {
                            "recipientId": "2",
                            "name": "recipient two",
                            "email": "recipienttwo@dsxtr.com",
                            "excludedDocuments": [ "1" ]
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "documents": [
                    {
                        "name": "Doc 1",
                        "fileExtension": "doc",
                        "documentId": "1",
                        "documentBase64": ""
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "Doc 2",
                        "fileExtension": "doc",
                        "documentId": "2",
                        "documentBase64": ""
                    }
                ]
            }
        ],
        "compositeTemplateId": "1"
    }
   ]
}
```

Comment: But the completion mail is sent after all signers signs the documents! Is there any way we can tackle that also?

Comment: An envelope is considered complete only when all the recipients finish signing. A completion mail will only be sent after all recipients complete signing.

Comment: Okay. Got it! So I think I need to stop that completion mail!

Comment: I am getting below error when I am adding SignHere Tab in Signer. "errorCode": "CANNOT_EXCLUDE_DOCUMENT",
  "message": "This document cannot be excluded for this recipient. Recipient:

Comment: @AnmolNimbalkar can you please post a new question with your complete Json and the steps you are taking.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're looking for [documentVisibility](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/Envelopes/Envelopes/create/#documentVisibility) on the create envelope call.

There are other supporting documentVisibility endpoints [here](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/Envelopes/EnvelopeDocumentVisibility/).

Comment: Thanks for your response!