# Documents restrictions within a package

Tags: docusignapi

I have looked through the DocuSign documentation, StackOverflow and Google but without success.
When creating a package, is it possible to restrict signers to be able to view certain pages of the document ? 
Let's say my borrower Lisa Smith should not be allowed to see the pages 5 to 10 while a second borrower can only be allowed to see pages 1 to 5, is that possible to do within the Rest API ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the DocuSign [document visibility](https://support.docusign.com/en/guides/ndse-user-guide-document-visibility) feature.

> If you send a document containing multiple files and you want to control which files each recipient sees, you can use document visibility to accomplish this. A common scenario is you want recipients to see only those files which they need to sign. With document visibility, you can create one document with files intended for individual recipients, rather than having to create a separate document for each recipient.

Using Document Visibility you can set access at document level. However setting access at page level is not supported.

See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42615330/1219543) on how to set documentVisibility using the rest api.

For more context, look for the excludedDocuments property on this [page](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/Envelopes/EnvelopeRecipients/#core-recipient-parameters).